# How to get Zurb Foundation's flexbox classes working?

Tags: css, flexbox, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using Foundation 6 and want to apply the Flexbox classes to a row and columns, as described in the documentation [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox.html).

My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="row header align-middle">
  <div class="large-5 columns">
    <div class="header__title">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-7 columns search-form">
    <form>etc</form>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I get nothing here. I also tried using the `align-self-middle` class on the column elements, to no affect, eg:

```
  <div class="large-7 columns search-form align-self-middle">
```

and tried a combination of both.

In the inspector I do see some styles being applied from framework.css, eg:

```
.align-middle {
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Would anyone know what I need to get this working?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? It would help if you put together a demo of the issue in your post on SO, then we could tell you for sure if it's working for you or not. Btw, "align-items: center;` aligns the contents vertically in a `flex-direction: row;` layout. And the `.align-self-middle` element is aligned center vertically http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqVJGX

Comment: I am having the same issue where the cell is not being aligned vertically centered like described here https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/NgwOxe?editors=1000 when using align-self-middle class.  I tried the solution below, but still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the scss version, in `app.scss` there is the following includes.

```
// @include foundation-grid;
@include foundation-flex-grid; 

//@include foundation-float-classes;
@include foundation-flex-classes;
```

Comment out `foundation-grid` & `foundation-float-classes` and uncomment `foundation-flex-grid` & `foundation-flex-classes`

Comment: Thanks. But why comment out those other files?

Comment: @MeltingDog If you're using the flex classes, you don't need the float classes.

Comment: I am having the same issue where the cell is not being aligned vertically centered like described here codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/NgwOxe?editors=1000 when using align-self-middle class. I tried this solution, but still nothing.  Here's my site: http://newsite.chanalevitan.com/  I would like the text in the header image to be vertically centered.

Comment: @MG1 Its working for me. I had a look in safari, firefox and chrome on mac.